# Как скрыть часть URL после того, как по нему перешли?

Tags: angularjs

во фронтенде абсолютный новичок, но эту проблему приходится решать мне. Пользователь переходит по ссылке(логинится), затем в строке URL браузера остаются параметры пользователя, которые он может вручную изменить. Подскажите пожалуйста, как скрыть параметры в строке URL после того, как пользователь перешел по ссылке?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы здорово добавить код, который отвечает за обработку формы

Comment: `$location.url($location.path())`

Answer (score 0):

Форму надо было post'ом отправлять, а не get'ом.

Ну и не хранить данные авторизации только на клиенте.